# Sorting Date and Time in an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to sort this Array in ascending order using Date & Time , The Array i want to sort is listed below:-

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 005
    [1] => 2011-09-12 12:28:46 
    [2] => IN 
    [3] => GATE1 
    [4] => NULL 
) 

Array (
     [0] => 003 
     [1] => 2011-09-12 12:23:43 
     [2] => IN 
     [3] => GATE1
     [4] => NULL 
)

Array (
    [0] => 001
    [1] => 2011-09-12 12:23:37
    [2] => IN
    [3] => GATE1
    [4] => NULL 
) 

Array ( 
    [0] => 002 
    [1] => 2011-09-12 12:23:34
    [2] => IN 
    [3] => GATE1 
    [4] => NULL 
)

Array ( 
    [0] => 012 
    [1] => 2011-09-12 12:23:29
    [2] => OUT 
    [3] => GATE1
    [4] => NULL 
)

Array ( 
    [0] => 010 
    [1] => 2011-09-12 12:23:25 
    [2] => OUT 
    [3] => GATE1 
    [4] => NULL 
)
```

Comment: try `usort` or look at "Related" list there ----->

Comment: please use var_export instead of print_r when dumping arrays

Comment: Thanks for your reply friends, but the issue i am facing is that i want to sort the whole array this is the data i get from my time attendance system so just sorting the date and not the id or anything will create problems for me. 

I want to sort out the date + time entry in ascending and in result i would like the system to generate me a same kind of array but in ascending not descending because the data is already in descending i want to sort it in ascending. 

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a[1], $b[1]);
});
```

Or with PHP < 5.3:

```
function sort_cb($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a[1], $b[1]);
}
usort($array, 'sort_cb');
```

Try it here: http://codepad.org/J8U2G32A

Alternatively, with [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort):

```
$dates = array_map(function($a) { return $a[1]; }, $array);
array_multisort($array, $dates);
```

Comment: Usort accepts callback as second argument, array_map - as first ;-) PHP is all about this

Comment: Thanks for your reply friends, but the issue i am facing is that i want to sort the whole array this is the data i get from my time attendance system so just sorting the date and not the id or anything will create problems for me. 

I want to sort out the date + time entry in ascending and in result i would like the system to generate me a same kind of array but in ascending not descending because the data is already in descending i want to sort it in ascending. 

Please help.

Comment: @arnaud it is just returning me the ascended date , but not the whole array.

Comment: it returns nothing, it sorts the array directly :) (after you call usort(), the array is sorted; same for array_multisort())

Comment: @arnaud , if i upload it on my server will you be kind enough to check it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but my data is not an array in an array its simply 

array(
'005',
'2011-09-12 12:28:46',
'IN',
'GATE1',
NULL,
),
array(
'003',
'2011-09-12 12:23:43',
'IN',
'GATE1',
NULL,
),

can you tell me a way so that i can convert it into the one you are suggesting? or anyother way to ascend it?

Comment: in my script i am writing $joinFields = array($userid,$timeentry,$event,$terminal,$jpegPhoto); to make an array which gives me the data array(
        '005',
        '2011-09-12 12:28:46',
        'IN',
        'GATE1',
        NULL,
    ),
    array(
        '003',
        '2011-09-12 12:23:43',
        'IN',
        'GATE1',
        NULL,
    ), i want the system not to generate an array like this but an array like this :-